# Can't locate element using By.XPATH contains(text()

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Hello dear stackoverflow wizards!

i'm trying to return an array of elements which contains a specific text as xpath.

The xpath element is this: //*[@id="produtoNCM_50"]

i have a sequence of 27 elements following this term:

1. //*[@id="produtoNCM_50"]
2. //*[@id="produtoNCM_51"]
3. //*[@id="produtoNCM_52"]
4. //*[@id="produtoNCM_n"]

i want to return all the web elements in a list, so i've tried to use the contains(text() approach, but it can't find the element. here's the code

```
import pandas as pd
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time
import os
from pprint import pprint

servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

navegador = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, service=servico)
```

my first try was:

```
navegador.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[contains(text(), "regra_")]'))
```

But it returns the error:**TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**

Then i've tried

```
navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(), "regra_")]')
```

But it returns another error: **NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), "regra_")]"}
(Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide a DOM for this problem?

Comment: /html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input[2]

Comment: No.. may be the Image or copied text of the Elements, when you inspect the element

Comment: https://ibb.co/0VxdFqK

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be looking for text based on what we have from your code. If you want to find those elements you should look for the ID that you already mentioned at the top

```
WebDriverWait (driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, 'produtoNCM_50')]")))
```

and you can take that one step further and put it into a loop

```
for i in range(50, 77, 1):
    WebDriverWait (driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, 'produtoNCM_"+ i +"')]")))
```

From the screenshot you provided of the input you are looking at there is no text available inside the input and no children.